# If $X \perp Y$ and $X \perp Y | Z$ , is that true that $X \perp Z$ or $Y \perp Z$ if $X$ and $Y$ can take 3 values but $Z$ only takes two.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, bayesian-network

I have the following problem : If $X \perp Y$ and $(X \perp Y )| Z$ , is that true that $X \perp Z$ or $Y \perp Z$ if $X$ and $Y$ can take 3 values but $Z$ only takes two.

$X \perp Y $ means $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $(X \perp Y )| Z$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $Z$.

I found a answer that shows that it is true when $X$ , $Y$ and $Z$ are binary variables, but I'm struggling when $X$ and $Y$ have not only 2 possibilities.

can someone help me finding a counter exemple or a glimpse of proof ?

thank you a lot.

Comment: Please define X⊥Y. Also define $X | Y$ and how parentheses should be inserted in X⊥Y|Z since they could be inserted in 2 ways.